# How to register a Windows phone over remote desktop connection?

Tags: lumia, 8.1, nokia-lumia-1020

I created a Windows 8.1 VM on Azure and installed VS 2013 Premium with update 2 on it. Then I tried to register my Lumia 1020 (WP 8.1 installed) using "Windows Phone Developer Registration 8.1" but it says "Unable to connect to a phone. Make sure that the Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) service is running.

So... I checked, the service is running indeed, but the Lumia phone on the VM's File Explorer shows up as a "MTP Device". I wonder what's wrong? But my local machine recognizes the phone.

Comment: To have 8.1 installed *at the moment* that would mean the phone is already developer unlocked, as you can currently only get 8.1 on the Developer Preview program.

Comment: @RowlandShaw, yes that's what I did.

Comment: So what are you trying to do, if you've already unlocked your phone?

Comment: @RowlandShaw, I'm trying to register the phone so that I can develop apps and then test on it.

Comment: But you *must* have done that to get 8.1 on it?

Comment: @RowlandShaw, I got WP8.1 on the phone by using Over The Air update.

Comment: It's been reported that it's not likely to be available generally until June 24th, and my 1020 reports no updates available?

Comment: @RowlandShaw, to get the preview to your phone, you'll have to install the preview app. details here http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-81-now-available

Answer (score 1):

"Windows 8.1 VM on Azure" <- I think this is your problem. You're RDPing into an Azure VM? That doesn't sound like it will work. There's some information about using a *local* VM [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator), which I think is your best bet if you don't want to install Windows 8.1 on your local machine.

Comment: Why would a local VirtualBox VM would work but not a Azure VM? My local hardware doesn't have enough resource to host a Windows 8.1 guest, that's why I went with Azure VM.

Comment: There would be no way for a VM running on Azure to communicate with your phone connected to a local PC. The WP8 SDK assumes the phone has a local/physical connection!